# Angular 6 Universal service provided in Injector needs another app injected variable

Tags: javascript, angular, dependency-injection, angular-universal

I am using Angular Universal. I have created a `PlatformService` to detect which platform I am currently working on.

```
/* platform.service.js */

import { Injectable, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlatformService {

    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
    ) {
        this.platformId; // this is coming out undefined
    }

    isBrowser() {
        return isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId);
    }

    isServer() {
        return isPlatformServer(this.platformId);
    }
}
```

I am creating a `BaseComponent` for common handling of my route binded components.

```
/* base.component.ts */

import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { InjectorHolderService } from '@core/services/util/injector-holder.service';
import { PlatformService } from '@core/services/util/platform.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-base',
    template: '',
})
export class BaseComponent implements OnInit {

    protected platformService: PlatformService;

    constructor() {
        this.platformService = InjectorHolderService.injector.get(PlatformService);
        console.log(this.platformService);
    }
}
```

Since this component will be inherited by many components, I didn't want to pass the `PlatformService` through `super()`. So I decided to go with creating an `Injector`.

```
/* app.module.ts */

import { InjectorHolderService } from '@core/services/util/injector-holder.service';
import { PlatformService } from '@core/services/util/platform.service';

@NgModule({ ... })
export class AppModule {
    constructor() {
        InjectorHolderService.injector = Injector.create({
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: PlatformService,
                    useClass: PlatformService,
                    deps: [], // I think i need to put something here, but not sure.
                }
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

And a service which can hold all the injected module for future use.

```
/* injector-holder.service.ts */

import { Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InjectorHolderService {

    static injector: Injector;
}
```

But `@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object` is giving out `undefined`, because of which I am not able to detect the platform.

What am I missing here? or If there is a better approach to achieve the above functionality.

Please let me know if you guys need to see any other file.

Comment: found this link to be useful, but this approach is only working for client-side because of initialization in `main.ts` file. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/premier_developer/2018/06/17/angular-how-to-simplify-components-with-typescript-inheritance/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I am not sure whether the following approach is good or bad, currently, it is the only thing working for me. Would love to hear any new approach to it.**

Since `PlatformService` needed `@Inject(PLATFORM_ID)` which is provided only from `AppModule`, the new `Injector` I created was not able to find any value for `@Inject(PLATFORM_ID)` and hence undefined.

So, instead of using class `PlatformService` in `Injector`, now I am using `PlatformService`'s instantiated object and hence was able to access everything fine in `BaseComponent`.

Modified my `AppModule` like following:

```
/* app.module.ts */

import { InjectorHolderService } from '@core/services/util/injector-holder.service';
import { PlatformService } from '@core/services/util/platform.service';

@NgModule({ ... })
export class AppModule {
    constructor(
        private platformService: PlatformService,
    ) {
        InjectorHolderService.injector = Injector.create({
            providers: [
                {
                    provide: PlatformService,
                    useValue: this.platformService, // notice the change of key, using value not class
                    deps: [],
                }
            ]
        });
    }
}
```

**Will try to add a minimal repo to recreate this issue and share with you guys, If anyone wants to explore more.**